# In a Sci-Fi Novel with Multiple Planes of Existence, How Would You Travel from One Plane to Another?

Tags: science-fiction, teleportation

In this world I am trying to create, as of now, I have **tube-like things called Gateways** that basically connect four separate planes of existence to one central one (think of a cross, with the cross point being the location of the fifth plane). These planes are completely different from each other (not parallel realities or different points in time).
**Gateways are just portals.** Gateways can link two planes of existence together and allow people to cross over, and also (in a smaller degree) teleport you to another location on Earth. These tubes circulate energy to-and-from the planes to sustain existence on both ends - but I'm not sure if they are truly *physical* things. I need to change and solidify an idea. My method of traveling through gateways is vague and just relies on the idea that "greater forces are at play".
Are there any tools/materials/specific methods that come to mind when traveling through portals? More specifically, how would you think to move a human body from one place to another without actually *going* there. I've heard of "folding" time, but that could cause other complications. But maybe that's necessary?
Any and all feedback on how portal travel could work would be great, although I'm not really looking for hard scientific advice.

Comment: Are you asking about scientific basis for teleportation?

Comment: I am asking about teleportation yes. However, my type of story is on that line between sci-fi and fantasy, at least in my head. This isn't a hard-science-geared question (my plot deals with things like supernatural abilities and deity figures, if you get what I mean). But hey answers of any kind are appreciated thanks for looking ;)

Comment: Then, if you don't need to be scientific, but only logical, you can come up with many solutions. The exact mechanism would likely depend on how your "separate planes of existence" reconcile with existing physics.

Comment: Thank you Alexander!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want it to sound sciency and have a plausible basis, you could use wormholes. There's a [really great video on youtube by Kursgesagt](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9P6rdqiybaw) which explains what they are and possible ways in which they could be created and sustained. Wormholes would cover your galactic teleportation. As for your inter-planar transport, if wormholes exist naturally, the theory is that they would be linked by cosmic string which keeps both ends open, you could just say that each of the deities created one of these to their plane, assuming that your deities live on these planes. This would also be good for showing how powerful the deities are that they can keep wormholes indefinitely with little effort while maybe humans need to expend a lot more effort.

Comment: we don't answer questions by telling "watch this video". Once the video will be gone we want the answer to be still helpful.

Comment: @L.Dutch-ReinstateMonica That's not what this answer is saying. The video link is indicated in text to be an explanation of "what [wormholes] are and possible ways in which they could be created and sustained." Personally, the OP's description of "Gateways" sounds a lot like wormholes.

Comment: You guys are awesome. Thank you Chundermunger and L.Dutch - Reinstate Monica and Frostfyre I'll check out what I can

Answer (score 4):

### Quantum Mechanics, QED and QCD are stranger than science fiction, and mind-boggingly fantastical. Look no further.

Look no further than the [Copenhagen Interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copenhagen_interpretation) of Quantum Mechanics.

As light passes through two slits it forms an interference pattern. However, pulse the light to send only a photon and you get a dot in the location of an interference pattern, *influenced by photons that you have not sent yet or photons you have already sent.*

**What's more is that this phenomenon exists with electrons, atoms and even buckyballs (molecules).**

How can this be? Well, the Copenhagen Interpretation is that all particles exist as probabilities - the photons you 'haven't' sent yet interact with the one you did, in a probabilistic manner. In fact, *all particles in this universe can exist in multiple locations in different probabilities*. Their position and momentum is defined in a Wave Function, in which it is impossible to determine precisely its location or its momentum until observed. Only when observed do you [collapse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_function_collapse) this 'wave function' to condense the probabilities into a result.

Quantum Field Theory is the theory that all particles are actually waves, oscillations in either an EM field, a quark field, or a Higgs field amongst others. It's predictions have been shown to be remarkably accurate.

It may be possible to take advantage of the quirks of quantum mechanics, in fact the entire modern Electronics industry does, but imagine if we can control how quarks interact, or convert from one field to another (not as hard as it sounds, particles regularly interact within alternate fields, or decay into particles in other fields).

It is entirely, in fact likely, **that there are fields we have not yet detected**, and which influence, or not influence, existing matter and energy in fields we can detect.

If you could find a way to convert matter, your person, and 'decay' it into an alternate quantum field, it may be possible to enter a 'side universe' parallel to our own, with interaction dependant on how the field interacts with EM, Quark and Higgs fields, and thus 'our' universe. Decaying our particles could convert again to our universe. Simple methods are used to alter particles, such as impacting our bodies with a certain radiation at an energy level tuned to alter its state.

Look into [Feynman Diagrams](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_diagram) to see how this process could work, with particles (virtual ones or ones that don't exist yet) regularly 'popping in and out of existence' interacting with particles to change their state or alter from one field to another.

The world of Quantum mechanics is magical and awe inspiring - the deeper you go the more you realise how strange the world really is.

Answer (score 2):

If that is fantasy, **make anything that suits your story**.

Otherwise there might be problem with "planes are completely different" - if you mean different physical laws, it maybe won't be a good idea to travel with your own body, because it could cause molecules inside your body to act "differently" - solution for this would be to use something like [Avatars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avatar_(2009_film)) (or [Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Matrix)). Also these kind of portals have to be in outer space.

If you have only slightly different physical laws - like in [The Gods Themselves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Gods_Themselves) (Asimov, Second part of the book) - there are portals used to generate energy, but:

> it could affect laws in both universes = laws would be "more similar" after some time, and it is also problem - Stars exploding in the book.

You can use Black holes ([Time holes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backwards_(novel)) - Red dwarf), tears in reality, some creatures to travel ([angels](https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/Weeping_Angel) or [oil](https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/Sentient_oil)/[Heather](https://tardis.fandom.com/wiki/Heather_(The_Pilot)) - Doctor who), include non-euclidian portals ([like this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kEB11PQ9Eo8)), duplicate teleportation (copy molecules in your destination - Outer limits 7/8 [Think like a dinosaur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_The_Outer_Limits_(1995_TV_series)_episodes)), some item or artifact with unknown origin (Key in [Robot City](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_Asimov%27s_Robot_City:_Odyssey) - Asimov, [Communication stones](https://stargate.fandom.com/wiki/Long-range_communication_stone) from Star Gate, [Portkey](https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Portkey) - Harry Potter), magic ([Dark portal](https://wow.gamepedia.com/Dark_Portal) - WoW), some wibbly wobbly thing (portal in [Contact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contact_(1997_American_film))) or use portals that were already there (in [Mostly harmless](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mostly_Harmless) - The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy series).

You don't have to explain exact technology when main character don't understand it anyway, only idea behind it (Most things already mentioned plus Star Trek, Star Wars, and many more)

Comment: Jan Ivan that's a lot of helpful information. Thanks for your time - and good final point I've thought about that but I'm glad to see a second opinion.